# Why is my python script not running from command line?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to run a simple python script from my command line. It works fine when I run the python script on its own but when I call it from the command line nothing happens. I don't even get an error. Python is added to my path. This is what I'm doing.

```
cmd C:\users\RGilsburg\Desktop\a\untitled1.py
```

The command prompt just proceeds to print the Microsoft Version and copyright details.

Anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: You should give some of your code to have precise answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the script

```
python C:\users\RGilsburg\Desktop\a\untitled1.py
```

Comment: For this to work you also need to make sure that your python interpreter has been added to your PATH variable.